# Use of configuration variables with `bal test` in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to pass some configuration variables to my Ballerina tests. I have two different sets of variables for the different contexts (Tests are running locally and on GitHub with Actions). For local tests, the variables can be defined in `tests/Config.toml` and it works as expected.

Now, I need to pass a different set of variables to my tests when running on GitHub Actions.
Since `bal test` does not support `-Ckey=value` variable setting, and environment variables do not override `Config.toml`, what is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 3):

We can pass configurable values with CLI arguments for the `bal test` command. This feature is available from `2201.6.0`.
The CLI syntax is as follows,

```
    bal test -Ckey=value
```

Please find the relevant documentation here.
https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/configure-tests/#define-test-specific-configurations

Answer (score 0):

With the current support of Ballerina, the best way is to use `os:getEnv` to read variables manually.

Comment: Isn't this a feature gap in `bal test`?

Comment: There is a GitHub issue to track this feature gap and make the improvement. https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/1163